# Generar informe excel mes a mes relleno

Tags: python

Quiero Realizar este informe y que se vaya ejecutando mes a mes, y me rellene vaya completando las celdas de el mismo fichero con los resultados de cada mes, pero no que me haga un fichero nuevo ya que perdería el mes anterior y no consigo la forma de hacerlo automatizado a ver si sabéis alguna forma de solucionarlo.

```
   try:
        # Crear nombre fichero excel
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Informe.xlsx')

        # Creamos las hojas
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Operaciones")

        # Creamos las cabeceras fijas
        worksheet.write('D3', datetime.now().strftime("%b-%y"), formato_canales)

        worksheet.merge_range('B5:B7', 'Active Users', merge_format)

        worksheet.write('C5', 'SMS', formato_canales)
        worksheet.write('C6', 'Web', formato_canales)
        worksheet.write('C7', 'Mobile', formato_canales)

            # Resultado de la consulta
            result_active_users_sql = active_users.fetchall()

            lista = []
            for row in result_active_users_sql:
                lista.append(row[0])

            row = 0
            col = 0

            for number in lista:
                worksheet.write_number(row + 4, col + 3, number, formato_canales)
                row += 1

    finally:
        workbook.close()
```

Como me sale: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como quiero que me salga: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se me ocurre que puedes cargar un `.csv` aparte del Excel, y actualizar eso, y luego importarlo en el Excel como una fuente y sacar una tabla dinámica basada en la info histórica del csv generado. Claro que tienes que hacer click en "actualizar" en el Excel, pero igual es simple

Answer (score 2):

Desde que haces

```
worksheet.write('D3', datetime.now().strftime("%b-%y"), formato_canales)
```

ya es muy difícil que se te generen columnas nuevas.
Tienes que poner una lógica condicional aquí que te vaya moviendo la columna en la que quieres trabajar, de acuerdo a las que ya llenaste.
Luego usas esa como col en vez de cero, y el write_number debería funcionar bien